# Which protocols does RabbitMQ use?

Tags: rabbitmq, protocols

Which are the communication protocols used by RabbitMQ when sending messages from the producer to the RabbitMQ broker and from the broker to the producer? How can I change between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please checkout:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/protocols.html

`AMQP`

`STOMP`

`MQTT`

`AMQP 1.0`

`HTTP`

By default it uses `AMQP`